# Unable to insert row in table using mysqli (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, syntax, reserved-words

I am trying to insert a row in a table but its giving me syntax error.

Here is the HTML Code:

```
    <form method="post" action="" >
    <!--form fields-->

    <div class="control-group">

    <div class="customer_data">
    <div class="controls" id="id_milesPerDay">

    <label for="ICAO" class="left-text">ICAO:</label>

    <input type="text" id="ICAO" style='text-transform:uppercase'  maxlength="4" name="ICAO" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
     </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="IATA" class="left-text">IATA:</label>

    <input type="text" name="IATA" maxlength="3" style='text-transform:uppercase' id="IATA" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="airportname" class="left-text">Airport Name:</label>

    <input type="text" name="airport_name" maxlength=""  id="Airport_Name" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="coordinates" class="left-text">Coordinates:</label>

    <input type="text" name="coordinates" maxlength=""  id="Coordinates" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="Time_zone_UTC" class="left-text">Time Zone UTC:</label>

    <input type="text" name="Time_zone_UTC" maxlength="3"  id="Time_zone_UTC" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="DST" class="left-text">DST:</label>

    <input type="checkbox" name="dst" value="other"  id="DST" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
    </div>

    <div class="controls text">
    <label for="utc" class="left-text">UTC:</label>

    <input type="text" name="utc" maxlength="3"   id="UTC" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
    </div>

    <div class="controls text">
    <label for="From_date" class="left-text">From Date:</label>

    <input type="date" name="from_date" maxlength=""   id="fromdate" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">

    </div>
    <div class="controls text">
    <label for="To_date" class="left-text">To Date:</label>

    <input type="date" name="to_date" maxlength=""   id="todate" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge">
    </div>  
    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="control-group">
    <div class="controls">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="Submit" class="btn btn-success" name="Submit">  
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="customer_aircraft">
    <div class="controls">
    <label for="country_code" class="left-text">Country Code:</label>

    <input type="text"  name="country_code" maxlength="2" style='text-transform:uppercase'  id="countrycode" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="Remarks" class="left-text">Remarks:</label>

    <textarea cols="25" rows="7"  name="remarks"  id="remarks" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge"></textarea> 

    </div>

    <div class="controls">
    <label for="Country" class="left-text">Country:        </label>

    <input type="text"  name="country" maxlength=""   id="country" placeholder="" class="input-xlarge" required>
    </div>
    </div>

   </div>       
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

PHP Code:

```
     <?php

     $link=require ("Connection.php");

     error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);


     if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
      {
   $ICAO= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['ICAO']);
   $IATA= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['IATA']);
   $Airport_Name= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['airport_name']);
   $coordinates= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['coordinates']);
   $Time_zone_UTC= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['Time_zone_UTC']);
   $DST= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['dst']);
   $UTC= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['utc']);

   $from_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['from_date']);

   $to_date =   mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['to_date'];


   $country_code= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['country_code']);
   $remarks= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['remarks']);
   $Country= mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$_POST['country']);


   //inserting records//

     $sql="INSERT INTO airport_data (ICAO,IATA,Airport_name,Coordinates,Time_zone_utc,DST,UTC,From,To,Country_code,Remarks,Country) VALUES ('$ICAO','$IATA','$Airport_Name','$coordinates','$Time_zone_UTC','$DST','$UTC',STR_TO_DATE('$from_date', '%m/%d/%y'),STR_TO_DATE('$to_date', '%m/%d/%y'),'$country_code','$remarks','$Country')";
    if(mysqli_query($link, $sql))
    {
    echo "Records added successfully.";
    }
    else
    {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }

    // close connection
    mysqli_close($link);




    } 

    ?>
```

Here is the error I receive:

> ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO airport_data (ICAO,IATA,Airport_name,Coordinates,Time_zone_utc,DST,UTC,From,To,Country_code,Remarks,Country) VALUES ('oprn','op','islamabad airport','islam','+9','other','+8',STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-26', '%m/%d/%y'),STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-20', '%m/%d/%y'),'op','p','Pakistan'). You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From,To,Country_code,Remarks,Country) VALUES ('oprn','op','islamabad airport','i' at line 1

Answer (score 2):

Escape (at least) reserved words in column names.

```
... `From`, `To`, ...
```

Full list of MySQL reserved words is in http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/reserved-words.html.

Comment: I tried but it didnt help.. i even changed the name of my DB coulumn from 'From' to 'From_date' likewise 'To_date' but same error. I personally think the way iam inserting date is not the rite way

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: escaping column names must solve this problem. Rename columns too. You maybe have any error message again, but not the same.

Comment: after using backticks error is "Column 'From_date' cannot be null"

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: so the error message is clear, isn't it?  From_date can't be NULL, check `$from_date` value.

Comment: actually its getting the date from calendar in text box see this error----> "ERROR: Could not able to execute INSERT INTO airport_data (ICAO,IATA,Airport_name,Coordinates,Time_zone_utc,DST,UTC,`From_date`,`To_date`,Country_code,Remarks,Country) VALUES ('oprn','op','op','op','op','other','op',STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-13', '%d/%m/%y'),STR_TO_DATE('2015-05-23', '%d/%m/%y'),'o','pop','op'). Column 'From_date' cannot be null  "

Comment: @AmmarUlHassan: sorry, I can't help you more. Try to `dump` form data, value is NULL for some reason. It's probably typo, check it yourself.

Comment: Thanks Done. i had to change my date formatting. will update in question as answer

Answer (score 0):

from and to are reserve keyword. Avoid to use them as column name. You need to change these column name.

You can find more details [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: you can use them but need to set in backticks

Comment: @sergio: not quotes, `'`, but backticks.

Comment: I tried but same error i renamed my columns in DB still same error

Comment: @sergio after using backticks error is "Column 'From_date' cannot be null"

Answer (score 0):

Actually the format of my date variables was wrong so i had to change it like

```
    $from_date = new DateTime($_POST['from_date']);
    $to_date = new DateTime($_POST['to_date']);

    Insert the following into the database
    $from_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $from_date->format('Y-m-d'));
    $to_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $to_date->format('Y-m-d'));
```

And in query
some thing like

```
    ,'".$from_date."','".$to_date."',
```